# Meteor in mobile

Tags: mobile, meteor

I have been into meteor development lately. The app is for mobile. But when I build and run the app in mobile device, it gets freaking slow.

Does this slowness be there if I deploy my app? Has anyone tried so.
And are there any best practices to for the development.

Like wise, when I change some files in the client, the hot code push takes really long time to reflect, about 5mins, hence its consuming lots of development time.

Comment: are you using `emulator` or `physical device` for development

Comment: Both is taking long time.